# Django login failing after registration

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I have a simple registration form that feeds this function in `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def registerNewUser(request):
  newUser = User.objects.create_user(request.POST["username"], request.POST["email"], request.POST["password"])
  newUser.last_name = request.POST["lastName"]
  newUser.first_name = request.POST["firstName"]

  print newUser.last_name

  user = authenticate(username = request.POST["username"], password = request.POST["password"])
  print user 

  if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
      login(request, user)
      print "Login Successful"
  else:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"login" : "failed"}))
```

I can see the new records being inserted in the `AuthUser` table, but the login is failing and the HttpResponse JSON error message is returning to the client.  In addition,

```
print user
```

is returning None

Why?

A final note:  The `last_login` field of the `auth_user` table shows an identical timestamp to the `date_joined` field.

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: the HttpResponse JSON message returning to the browser.  I made a clarification at the very end of the question.

Comment: On a sidenote, You are not doing a `save` after you assign `first_name` and `last_name`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I got bit by duplicate entries by using `create()` and `save()` on the same call, and forgot about it.

Comment: [authenticate returns None if password is invalid](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) - One more question, is the `create_user` creating the `User` object with the correct fields ?

Comment: That was it.  It turned out that I had two input fields with the same ID in the form, and the password field used on submission was empty.

Answer (score 1):

In case login succeeds, your view does not `return` anything to the client. Views in django *must* return an `HttpResponse` object.

```
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        print "Login Successful"
        # (1) Missing return statement here
    else:
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"login" : "failed"}))

# (2) Execution flow falls through to here
```

But you mentioned that the message is in JSON format... Did you submit all the code for your view?

It's very likely that the flow of execution just "falls through" to the code that is after the `if user is not None` statement - which I assume is your `User is None` case.

Comment: That error you pointed out was my mistake in formatting for this question.  I just double checked the code and the `else` statement is indeed after `if user is not None`  Still, this doesn't explain why `print user` is returning None after the authenticate call.